# How do I implement OAuth on a mobile device? Do I have to run a localhost server?

Tags: android, ios, oauth-2.0, flutter

I'm a web developer and I've implemented Oauth a couple times. I would forward the user to a login screen on a third-party page, then it would send the user back to my server.

But I'm making an android app (using flutter) at the moment, and I'm confused. Do I do the same thing? Do I start a web server on the users phone, then send the user to a sign in page then let the server handle the user coming back?

These seems complex for an app. Or am I thinking of this wrong?

Extra:

On flutter, it's very frustrating because when the user finishes authenticating, they are taken back to my server and I now have to close the web browser for them... which is difficult to do since the in-app browsers don't run javascript where I can just run `window.close();` in it.

Comment: With google and iOS, and I assume most others, you will go through an OAuth flow on client side only and then send some token to your server to then do server side validation. This link helped me when I implemented this for iOS https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth

Comment: @roboyby I don't see a link. Did you run a web server on the user's phone?

Comment: You create a Custom URI scheme (the redirect URI).. IE: `myapplication` and then for your oAuth `authorize` call, you specify: `redirect_uri=myapplication://oauth` and in AppDelegate's `OpenURL` you will get a url such as `myapplication://oauth?code=blahblah&state=1` then make the call to `tokenize` and you will get a reply back such as: `myapplication://oauth?token=blahblah&state=2`

etc.. There's no need for webviews or servers or anything.. You can use a webview, but if you really want to, then use `SFAuthenticationSession` or `ASWebAuthenticationSession` (iOS 12).

Comment: The link should be there now. What Brandon said is correct. You need to use a deep link instead of redirect uri like normal OAuth flows for the web. My comment above is for if you wanted to then sync that authenticated user with a backend service/database.

Comment: Thanks guys! Now the other queston: do I run a web browser and then close it for them? Do they have to manually close it themselves then manually switch back to my app?